# How can I send an email via Visual Flow that includes a record link?

Tags: email-template, visual-workflow, flow, visual-flows

I am fairly new to Flows and am working through a flow that sends an auto-notification email from a task, but rather than use an existing email alert to send the email, I am trying to build it within the flow. Is there a way to access a record's detail link from within Flow, or set it into a variable, so that it can be used similar to the "{!Task.Link}" merge field on a regular email template?

Thanks so much!!

Comment: Hi, are you trying to send an email with a link or I interpreted your question wrong?

Comment: If not, you can get the Id of the task then concatenate it in your SFDC instance, assign it in a variable then you're now free to use it along the way.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, you can pass the Task.Link via the button URL to a variable in the Flow.

https://www.interactiveties.com/blog/archive/pass-vars-url.php

Chris